# Right-to-left text in LaTeX - reversed numbers and parentheses

Tags: babel, hebrew, right-to-left

Finally I got my Hebrew working on LaTeX.

Everything's working great except for two issues - numbers and parentheses. Numbers are written the other way around (one hundred would be written 001), and parentheses are reversed too )like this(. Is there a solution for the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
המספר (מאה) בספרות הוא 100
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This should provide context within which you use Hebrew numbers and parentheses for others to work with.

Comment: I cannot test your MWE due to missing fonts issues, but have you tried using the `\foreignlanguage` command from `babel` for short text in a different language? Something like `\foreignlanguage{english}{100}`

Comment: Better yet, according to `hebrew.dtx` you can use the switch `\unsethebrew` to switch from the Hebrew font encoding to the current font encoding, and from the right-to-left mode to left-to-right mode. The command `\sethebrew` switches back.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean, then, that I have to use these commands every time I use numbers or parenthesis? I thought there was something I could write at the beginning or something, and afterwards I would be able to type normally?

Comment: As someone who started with LaTeX and Babel a few weeks ago, let me save you some headaches: use XeTeX and polyglossia instead. Things like this work there out of the box, and other little quirks that Babel has are working fine there.

Comment: @daniel.jackson: Why not make your comment an answer? (Give an MWE as well).

Comment: @daniel.jackson I tried XeTeX, but the compilation is terribly slow.
At least for numbers, there is a simple solution: put them in math mode. E.g, $100$ looks like 100.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Artyom Beilis' [**BiDiTex**](http://biditex.berlios.de/), which pre-processes a (La)TeX file to reverse parentheses and enclose numbers in appropriate macros.

The [documentation](http://biditex.sourceforge.net/biditex-doc.pdf) lists the problem you mention exactly, in section 1... that's the motivation for writing that utility.

Using the question's MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biditex}
%BIDION
\begin{document}
המספר (מאה) בספרות הוא 100
\end{document}
%BIDIOFF
```

And running

```
cat mwe.tex | biditex.exe -o mwe_out.tex
```

you get:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biditex}
\begin{document}
המספר )מאה( בספרות הוא \Lnum{100}
\end{document}
```

Which results when LaTeXing in the output you'd expect:

[image: Output]

Of course, you would want to scriptify all of this.

By the way, BiDiTeX seems to require UTF-8 input.

Answer (score 5):

I agree daniel.jackson, Polyglossia and XeTeX are the way to go.  Here's my working example, though minimal it is not:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%polyglossia packages - polyglossia must be first
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}

%XeTeX packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}

%settings for packages
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Here is a whole phrase or section in left-to-right direction:

\setRL
 הנשיא האמריקאי ברק אובמה נאם הערב (שישי) בוועידת הקהילות היהודיות שנערכה בוושינגטון.
\unsetRL

Or, for when a few words will do:

\RL{\ldots נאם הערב (שישי) בוועידת\ldots}

And it works fine with numbers as well:

\RL{\ldots נאם 100 + 30 = 130 הערב (שישי) בוועידת\ldots}

Even nested environments work just fine:

\RL{\ldots נאם \LR{with English in the middle} הערב (שישי) בוועידת\ldots}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `bidi`, `fontspec`, `xltxtra` and `xunicode` are all unnecessary. And in fact it's necessary to load `polyglossia` last more often than not.

Comment: I agree that xltxtra, and xunicode are unnecessary (though they are in my template so I rarely remove them) but the commands I issued \RL{}, \setRL, etc. are command for the bidi package and the command \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O) is for the fontspec package.  I was under the impression that the standard font did not have many non-latin glyphs.

Comment: Right, but both of those are included by `polyglossia`, so there's no need to explicitly load them.

Comment: Huh... I did not know that.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @daniel.jackson It's not `polyglossia` that has to be last.  It's the line `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}` that has to go after any other package loading, because that line loads `bidi`.