# Numbers, punctuation and parenthesis reversed in RTL

Tags: xetex, hebrew, right-to-left

Contrary to my belief and to what's shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38421/right-to-left-text-in-latex-reversed-numbers-and-parentheses), the above are coming up reversed for me:

[image]

I've seen this happen in other places too (enumerations off the top of my head), but these are the most bothering.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}
\begin{document}
מספר 1.

משהו )בסוגריים(.
\end{document}
```

Since the display here is having a hard time with the Hebrew and parenthesis, this is how it looks in an editor:

[image]

And RTL (note that the parenthesis are correct because they look properly in RTL rather than LTR):

[image]

And when numbers and parenthesis are combined, there's a whole party going on:

[image]

Comment: First note that my question, which you linked to, is not about xetex + polyglossia. As for your example, you're trying to flip the parentheses, and you shouldn't. Your latex code does _not_, I believe, match your screenshots. You wrote MASHEHU, then left paren instead of right, then BESOGRAIM, then right paren instead of left.

Comment: EyalRozenberg: I was referring to the last answer there, by AdamRedwine. The latex code is identical - I took the screenshots all at once. I included the LTR/RTL screenshots for exactly this reason that the text displayed is confusing. But you can see in the LTR shot that the first paren is a **right** one and the last is a **left**. This is evident in that it looks right in RTL.

Comment: In the screenshot, you're right, but in the LaTeX code above, it's the other way around. Really.

Comment: EyalRozenberg: I think you might be right, although I'm confused myself now. But even if we ignore the inverted parenthesis, there's still the other issues.

Comment: If you edit the question to include just the period at the end of the line, maybe it'll get some more attention... and if that doesn't work we can offer a bounty.

Comment: I suspect the error might be located in a faulty input file. I have copied your code and it gives me the exact same output you have. But when I typed it in myself, I got a correct output. (I am using TeXShop on Mac OS X and Mac OS switches the input direction automatically, i. e. I see my input already correctly.)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same problem as with this example, and also with citation brackets. For parentheses I could just flip them myself, but I can't do that for citations. Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I guess my parentheses were also reversed, as the ones in the question, and the bracket thing was solved by moving the `\cite` command out of the `\LR` it was previously in.

Comment: @brian-ammon Please convert your comment into an answer, so that this question can be removed from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error might be located in a faulty input file. I have copied your code and it gives me the exact same output you have. But when I typed it in myself, I got a correct output. (I am using TeXShop on Mac OS X and Mac OS switches the input direction automatically, i. e. I see my input already correctly.)