# Rstudio output in Hebrew

Tags: sweave, hebrew, knitr

(Follow-up to
[Making LaTeX documents with Hebrew? (in Sweave + RStudio)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46506/making-latex-documents-with-hebrew-in-sweave-rstudio/56637#56637))

Trying to reproduce the above answer, I followed these instructions without success, under Windows 7.

The best result I got so far is a document containing correct Hebrew text, but backwards (meaning RTL) R output. It means that the whole document is right-aligned, even the English parts.

BTW, I was using the knitr function, as sweave was not functioning at all. My Encoding is UTF-8.

I would appreciate any tips or solution!

MWE:

```
%  This document must be compiled with Sweave and xelatex (not pdflatex)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave} % you must load Sweave with the `noae` option
% load polyglossia late in the package load order, since the bidi package (which is
% loaded when an RTL language is set) redefines lots of package code.
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{David CLM}
% for R work with Hebrew, it's important to have a mono font that supports
% the Hebrew script.  Miriam Mono is one that I know of
\setmonofont[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}  
\title{\textenglish{Side-by-side xtables}}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
ראשית קצת קוד R כדי ליצור כמה נתונים.
<<>>=
myData <- matrix(c(19,89,23,23,74,44,16,39,67),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(myData) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(myData) <- c("1","2","3")
myData2 <- myData * 2
@

כעת אנו שמים את הנתונים בשני צדדי על ידי צד טבלאות:

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{\textenglish{First Table}}
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
library("xtable")
print(xtable(myData),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{\textenglish{Second Table}}
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
print(xtable(myData2),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData2)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@

\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(sorry, the system doesn't allow me to upload pics... but believe me, the whole page is right-aligned, and the R code is reversed)

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot compile Hebrew documents (I may need to install certain fonts), here is my guess which might work. Put this in your LaTeX preamble and see if it works:

```
\ifdefined\knitrout
 \renewenvironment{knitrout}{
  \begin{LTR}
 }{
  \end{LTR}
 }
\else
\fi
```

The `LTR` environment [was suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46506/making-latex-documents-with-hebrew-in-sweave-rstudio/46600#comment119253_46600) by Alan Munn, and I have no idea of it.