# xelatex and asian writing

Tags: fonts, xetex

I just managed to change font (thanks!) but now I have a problem... The text, once written in traditional asian form (top to bottom, right to left on pdflatex) is now normal.

So my question now is - can I have both? Changed font and traditional asian writing layout?

Comment: You mentioned pdfLaTeX, but the title and tags of your question point to Xe(La)TeX. How are you processing your files? Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38543) on the usage of [`polyglossia`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/polyglossia) for typesetting right-to-left on XeTeX (it loads some functionalities from [`bidi`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/bidi)).

Comment: What do you mean by "traditional Asian form"? For instance, in Arabic texts are typeset from right to left in each horizontal row and then rows are displayed from top to bottom, while in traditional Chinese texts are typeset from top to bottom in each vertical column firstly and then columns are displayed from right to left. Which language do you refer to? And please show a MWE.

Comment: @henrique pdflatex can't change font from what I've tried. I was able to do it with xelatex, but it caused the problem described. I don't see any of the languages I need in polyglossia...

Comment: @wenbo I think Chinese, Korean and Japanese at least, have that same traditional typeset. That's the one I meant. Nowadays not very used, but still...

Comment: Check [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17611) and [How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15516)